# Tomcat cant find method

Tags: java, tomcat, guava

I'm using Google Guava jar in order to find subsets and making a web application using tomcat. However, When i call the class having the Sets.powerSet function, Tomcat gives me an exception saying

> HTTP Status 500
>
> Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.collect.Sets.powerSet(Ljava/util/Set;)Ljava/util/Set;

```
public LinkedHashSet<Set<Item>> generateAllPossibilities(Multimap<Item, Item> largeItemset, Map<String, Multimap> ObjectInfo, double minSupport) {
    LinkedHashSet<Item> setOfItems = new LinkedHashSet(1000);
    Set<Item> objectKeys = largeItemset.keySet();
    setOfItems.addAll(objectKeys);
    /**
     * debug
     */
    /*
    for (Item keyprint : objectKeys) {
        System.out.print(keyprint.object + "\t\t" + keyprint.predicate + "\t\t");
        Collection<Item> values = largeItemset.get(keyprint);
        setOfItems.addAll(values);
        for (Item value : values) {
            System.out.print("{" + value.object + "\t\t" + value.predicate + "}");
        }
        System.err.println();
    }
     */
    /**
     * debug
     */
    /*
    System.out.println("Set of items is ");
    for (Item item : setOfItems) {
        System.out.println(item.object + "\t\t" + item.predicate);
    }
     */
    Set<Set<Item>> power = Sets.powerSet(setOfItems);
```

Comment: Are you sure you've compiled the same Guava version between your code and Tomcat?

Comment: Yea.. @cricket_007